# unity respawn after delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timedelay

I'm trying to respawn an object at "x" amount of time however when i use yield and startcourutine it causes a lot of errors and mistakes in my code. and instead of destroying i want to hide the object and enable it again when i respawn it after the delay. how is this possible if i have arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a direct respawn on the same position you can do this:

```
public class CrateCrash : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    public void InitRespawn(GameObject toRespawn)
    {
        StartCoroutine(RespawnObject(toRespawn, 5.0f));
    }

    private IEnumerator RespawnObject(GameObject toRespawn, float delay)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        toRespawn.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

The other class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Crate : MonoBehaviour
{   
    CrateCrash manager;    

    public void OnMouseDown()
    { 
        manager.InitRespawn(gameObject);

        gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }

    public void SetManagerReference(CrateCrash managerRef)
    {
        manager = managerRef;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hey gunnar! Thank you the yours following code do what i want however it justs disables the object and enables it back again. I want to assign for it new available position that i have and new type

Comment: @Alex So assign your new position and type in the `RespawnObject()` coroutine.

Comment: No, you can call them from the coroutine (instead of the `SetActive`) and pass the gameobject as parameter. Then instead of using `Instantiate` you call the `SetActive` there (and set the position, doesn't matter if you do that before or after `SetActive`).

Comment: @iggy How I'm getting an errors. its working but on time my free position gets 0 and its doesnt work after that